# Traffic layer in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to show the traffic layer for this location:
[map](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-34.611919,-58.431769&num=1&t=m&z=15&layer=t)

According to: [Google Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#TrafficLayer) I should only do this:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.04924594193164, -118.24104309082031);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
trafficLayer.setMap(map);
```

But the traffic layer is not shown.

I've checked this: [coverage spreadsheet](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html) and it says it is not covered, but if I go to maps.google.com and search that location I can see traffic layer.

Is this not open to the developer community? Is something that needs to be paid to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all data you see on maps.google.com are available inside the API, it's the decision of the owners of the data to spread their property for free or not.

Comment: Do you know how traffic is feeded? I mean, I don't think there is someone entering the data all day long, but I don't know exactly how it works.

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, but I guess the streets are full of sensors that log the traffic, e.g. how many vehicles are on the road and what's the average speed. Based on such data you may conclude the traffic-situation.

Comment: If it helps, I believe Googles Traffic Data is a mix of data taken from the countrys Highways agencies who get the data via traffic sensors, and Crowd Sourced data from Android (and other mobile devices i'm sure) with GPS Enabled. I did have a source for that info but I can't find it now :(